# Get the first element in a for loop with php

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

How can i add the active class only, just to the first element in this for loop?

```
for($i = 0; $i < $akcios_kepek_num; $i++)
{
  if($i == 1 ){
    $active = "active";
  }else{
    $active = "";
      }

   echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="'.$active.'"></li>';

}
```

I tryed to check it, with the `$i == 1` code, but it will add the active class to all the elemtnts.

Comment: First element is `$i == 0` not `$i == 1`

Comment: But it till gives the class to all the other elements.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Any debugging attempts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that should works. First element is `$i == 0` and I used ternary operator to replace `if/else` is little more elegant

```
for($i = 0; $i < $akcios_kepek_num; $i++)
{
   $active = $i == 0 ? "active" : "";
   echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="'.$active.'"></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$i must be 0 for first element, if you start from 0.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $akcios_kepek_num; $i++)
{
  if($i == 0 ){
    $active = "active";

  }else {
    $active = "";
  }

  echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="'.$active.'">test</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the condition were on second index, i mean your loop is starting from 0 so the first element will be 0 not 1,  also i added the short hand if statement if the value is 0 then it will add "Active" class otherwise it will add no class.

```
<?php
   for($i = 0; $i < $akcios_kepek_num; $i++)
   {
 
    echo '<li data-target="#carousel-example-3" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="'.($i == 0 ? "active" : "").'"></li>';
   }
?>
```